# Propel ORM - Criteria Class

Tags: php, orm, criteria, propel

I'm trying to learn Propel especially about the Criteria Class on http://api.propelorm.org/1.3.0/runtime/propel-util/Criteria.html#class_details..

But I'm having a hard time understanding this thru that page. Can anyone please provide me better sites where I can read or watch tutorials on Criteria Class (preferably with PHP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, if you want to start with Propel you should take a look at the last version, **1.6.9**, and not the 1.3.0.

**Second**, instead of diving into the code (even if it's a good idea), it's better to start with the official documentation, with concrete example: http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html

`Criteria` class are really related to Propel < 1.4.x. It's still exists in Propel 1.6.x, because it can achieve very complex query. But since the 1.6.0 version, there is `ModelCriteria` which handle query in more *readable* way, more human, more like Doctrine does.

ModelCriteria:

```
$books = BookQuery::create()
  ->useAuthorQuery('a', 'left join')
    ->filterByName('Leo Tolstoi')
  ->endUse()
  ->find();
```

Criteria:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(AuthorPeer::BOOK_ID, BookPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(AuthorPeer::NAME, 'Leo Tolstoi');
$books = BookPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But what they've been using is 1.3.0 so that's what I need to learn I guess.. Does this mean that there's no available tutorials for this version anymore? :(

Comment: @SandaraKwon You can find the *old* documentation of Propel [here](http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.3).